# Assimp with android port. Error import .obj file

Tags: android, android-ndk, assimp

I am built assimp for android with android port (AndroidJNIIOSystem). When I import a file from assets, I get message: **Assimp: Asset exists** and next get error: 
**Error::Assimp::No suitable reader found for the file format of file "model/nanosuit.obj".**

I have assets hierarchy:
assets/model/nanosuit.obj

My code:

```
importer.SetIOHandler(ioSystem);

auto modelPath = "model/nanosuit.obj";
const aiScene *scene =
        importer.ReadFile(modelPath, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs);

if (!scene || scene->mFlags & AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE || !scene->mRootNode) {
    LOGI("%s::%s", "Error::Assimp", importer.GetErrorString());
}
```

But then I use this code with assimp built for Linux, it work without any errors. Please, help me find solution. Thanks!

P.S. importer.IsDefaultIOHandler() returns false.

Comment: Cheked now. importer.GetImporterCount() returns 0. Build configuration may be is reason for it?

Answer (score 2):

When I build lib, I am use -DASSIMP_BUILD_ALL_IMPORTERS_BY_DEFAULT=OFF in order to reduce lib file size. If remove this flag, all works fine. That use .obj importer you need use -DASSIMP_BUILD_OBJ_IMPORTER=ON flag